# Wordpress wp_http_referer in url breaks navigation in 'Edit Category', ignores siteurl

Tags: wordpress

[Edit Category page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdQQo.png)

When I am editing the layout (e.g. Template, Sidebar) for a Wordpress category page (a.k.a. 'Edit Category') I have noticed that when the I navigate from the list of Categories, to the 'Edit Category' page, there is a parameter in the url: wp_http_referer, which does not respect my Wordpress siteurl (www.mysite.com/blog), and this results in an incorrect redirect after I edit and Update the category.

Why won't wordpress respect the siteurl in this situation?